# zero-order functions in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've started learning about Haskell and I'm trying to specify the Haskell type signature of an arbitrary zero-order function with Int type. As far as I understand, with first-order functions it would be something like `k :: Int -> Int`. Would that mean that the type signature of a zero-order function would be just `k :: Int`, or is it wrong to assume that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no "zero order" functions in Haskell. *Every* function in Haskell has an *arity* of 1: each function takes one argument, and it returns one value. The return value itself could be another function. (A higher-order function is one whose argument and/or return type is itself a function type.)

`k :: Int` is not a function; it's just an `Int`.

The closest thing to a function with arity 0 in Haskell is a function of type `() -> a` for some type `a`. Because there is only one value of type `()`, there is only one way to call the function: with `()`.

```
k :: () -> Int
k () = 3
```

(You might notice that there is exactly one function of type `() -> a` for each value of type `a`; that's a matter of some theoretical importance, but isn't really relevant to the question here.)

Comment: A function whose return type is itself a function is not higher-order.

Comment: Sure it is. https://wiki.haskell.org/Higher_order_function

Comment: Wow. While I now agree that multiple places agree on that definition, my *goodness* it is a useless one compared to what I thought it was. You're gonna tell me somebody thinks `(&&)` is some exotic object, a higher-order function?

Comment: It seems that some people are sane. "in a typed lambda calculus, higher-order functions that take one function as argument are values with types of the form (t1 -> t2) -> t3" -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Comment: I don't see that sentence as precluding `t1 -> t2 -> t3` as being a higher-order function. It refers to "higher-order functions that take one function as argument", not "higher-order functions *are* functions that take one function as argument".

Comment: I do see it that way. `t1 -> t2 -> t3` is not of the form `(t1 -> t2) -> t3`, and higher-order functions are values with types of the form `(t1 -> t2) -> t3`. It is very normal in mathematics to state "X is Y" as a definition, without feeling the need to list all of the things X is not.

Comment: That’s the historical mathematical definition of “higher order”, but that’s not really the way we use it in practice now in Haskell where currying is the norm. Informally, we call a function “*n*th order” if it’s isomorphic to an *n*th-order function; ditto *n*-ary. The differences are relevant in category-land: with Cartesian closure, you internalise “function” arrows as “closure” objects (exponentials). A function `f : A × B → C` is *partially* applied in `f(a, —) : B → C` while `g : A → C^B` is *fully* applied in `g a : C^B` (“allocating” a closure). In Haskell they’re both called `(->)`.

Comment: I understand but nevertheless would it make sense to define the type signature as k :: Int?

Comment: Sure, that's fine and accurately states what you are doing. It says that `k` is a value of type `Int`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a certain family of beliefs that start with "every function in Haskell has exactly one argument". Those beliefs are *useful*: they form the grounding of a very precise way to talk about Haskell and to understand the behavior of Haskell.

But they've always been a bit too strident for my taste. Despite the fact that the `->` type former is binary and so technically a function has one argument and one return type, I think it's nevertheless *also useful* to have a shorthand for talking and thinking about Haskell that allows you to mentally and verbally chunk a type like `a -> (b -> c)` as "a function with two arguments". The obvious generalization of arity is then to count up how many times you have to go to the right of an arrow before you get to a non-arrow type, so that `a -> (b -> c)` is arity 2, `Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool` is arity 3, and `Int` is arity 0. There's no problem with such definitions.

If you allow yourself that flexibility, then you can also talk more flexibly about order, so that the natural generalization of "order" is to count up how many times you can go to the left of an arrow before you are forced to bottom out at a non-arrow type. So, `Bool -> Bool` has order 1, `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` has order 2 (and arity 2), `((Int -> r) -> r) -> Cont r Int` has order 3... and in the world where you allow yourself that flexibility, I think it is *perfectly natural* to talk about `Int` as being an order-0, arity-0 function. (And, indeed, one can derive that all order-0 functions are arity-0.)

Comment: It couldn't apply to type variables, as `a -> a` has order depending on how `a` is instantiated.

Comment: @Iceland_jack Yes, some care must be taken in the presence of polymorphism. It is not insurmountable, though; for most purposes, it is fine to just take the simple approach and treat variables as not being functions.

Comment: @Iceland_jack Importantly, `id` cannot *use* its argument as a function, precisely because it is polymorphic. So we know from it's type that it cannot "do higher order things", which is some justification for simply saying that it *isn't* higher order.

Comment: Personally I prefer keeping "functions are things with types of the form `A -> B`". I would rather generalise the concept of arity to apply to non-function things in order to say "`Int` has arity zero", rather than saying "`Int` is an arity-zero *function*". I still want a word for things that can be applied to arguments to compute something. If "function" is redefined to include arity-zero values then it includes *all* Haskell values, and we already have a word for that: value.